# google script: issue with spreadsheet update when processed through trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet which prepares report and sends email. When I have the spreadsheet open in the browser, the spreadsheet gets updated with data and email sent with correct data (actually its a chart). 
If I put this code in a trigger, the email contains empty graph because the spreadsheet do not have data populated. The spreadsheet does a calculation and chart is drawn.

Anyways to fix this issue? So far I've got to know that if I have the spreadsheet open, then the trigger sends me email with required data, but if the spreadsheet is not open, the email contains empty chart.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think its because the script gets executed on the server..

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Comment: There can be a number of reasons... Can you please include some code? And here is more on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use getActiveSpreadsheet() and getActiveSheet() to get data from Spreadsheet.

Something like this :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
```

If  my assumption is true then use getSheetByName() or getSheets() instead of getActiveSheet()

Because getActiveSheet() return currently active spreadsheet only, but when it runs from a time-driven trigger there is no active sheet and graph drawing functionality can't fetch any data, so you need to indicate the sheet.

The line should look like this:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @YNK, I am doing exactly: var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("data");